# C program crashes

Tags: c, string, pointers

Hi I need some help with debugging my program: It should read from the Console, process the input and give it back out:

The error occures after `while(scanf("%15s", input) != EOF)` is called the 2nd time. Unfortunately I can't tell you what the error is, because the progam freezes and doesn't give me any Information. I think there is something wrong with the `input` var (it is passed multiple times)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* repeat(char c, int n);
char* drawLabel(char* label, int n);
char* drawBarnorm(char* label, int value);
char* drawBar(char* label, double value);

int main(void)
{
    char* input;
    double numIn;
    char buf[] = "";
    char* pOutput = &buf[0];

    while(scanf("%15s", input) != EOF)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &numIn);
        if (numIn > 1)
        {
            if (numIn > 30)
            {
                printf("num to big!\n");
                return 0;
            }

            strcat(pOutput, drawBarnorm(input, (int)numIn));
        } else
            {strcat(pOutput, drawBar(input, numIn));}


        printf("%s\n", pOutput);
    }

    printf("%s\n", pOutput);
    return 0;
}

char* repeat(char c, int n)
{
    char* out = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    int i, len;
    out[0] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        len = strlen(out);
        out[len] = c;
        out[len+1] = '\0';
    }

    return out;
}

char* drawLabel(char* label, int n)
{
    if (strlen(label) > n)
    {
        char* newLabel = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
        newLabel[0] = '\0';
        strncpy(newLabel, label, n);
        newLabel[n] = '\0';
        return newLabel;
    } else if (strlen(label) < n)
    {
        strcat(label, repeat(' ', n-strlen(label)));
    }

    return label;
}

char* drawBarnorm(char* label, int value)
{
    char* bar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*41);
    char* barPart;
    bar[0] = '\0';
    bar = drawLabel(label, 8);
    strcat(bar, "|");
    barPart = drawLabel(repeat('#', value), 30);
    strcat(bar, barPart);
    strcat(bar, "|");
    return bar;
}

char* drawBar(char* label, double value)
{
    int val = (int)(30.0*value);
    return drawBarnorm(label, val);
}
```

Thank you for helping me out with this.

Comment: You made the exact same mistake in this question as previous.

Comment: *Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it.* -- George Santayana.

Comment: this line: 'while(scanf("%15s", input) != EOF)' contains an error.  What the code really wants to look for is 'was the input/conversion successful?'  therefore, the correct way to write the line would be: 'while( 1 == scanf(" %15s", input))' I.E. 1 input conversion and leading ' ' in format string to skip over/absorb any leading white space, (like a newline).

Comment: the function: drawlabel() returns a pointer to a malloc'd area, so the line: 'bar = drawLabel(label, 8);' overlays the prior contents of 'bar', resulting in a memory leak because 'bar' was already set by a pointer to some malloc'd memory area

Comment: 1) always check the returned value from malloc() (and family) for successful operation.  2) for several reasons, do not cast the returned value from malloc (and family). 3) always free any malloc'd areas before exiting a program.  also free malloc'd areas when the areas are no longer needed.

Comment: the returned value from draw...() should be checked to assure the operation was successful, before using the returned pointer

Comment: both 'if' statements in function: drawlabel() are performing a comparison between signed and unsigned int.  this results in the compiler raising two warning messages.  1) all warnings should be enabled during the compile/link steps, 2) warnings actually need to be fixed.

Comment: I rolled back your question as your edit make the answers invalid (you corrected what was wrong). When you get the answer that solves your problem you should mark it as accepted, don't edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize `input` or declare it as an array like this

```
char input[16];
```

also, you should notice that `scanf` does not return `EOF` it returns the number of arguments matched, so you have to change

```
while(scanf("%15s", input) != EOF)
```

to

```
while(scanf("%15s", input) == 1)
```

because `while(scanf("%15s", input) != EOF` is always true.

Comment: Thx, that helped a lot. after I exit with an EOF I get a: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: Aha thats funny because I can exit the loop with EOF.

Comment: No you can't. The character sent is not what `scanf` returns, in that case it returns `0`, but since `0 != EOF` you enter the loop with `input` uninitialized, then when you trying to access `input` it's `UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR` which in your case is causing `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` apparently.

Answer (score 4):

```
char* input = malloc(size); /* Allocate memory of your wish */
```

Allocate memory to `input` You have not initialized your pointer.

The pointer should be pointing to some valid memory location to store the value through `scanf()`

Comment: You know there is a `free` function right? And what should the value of `size` be?

Comment: in the main() function, 'input' is defined as 'char input[40]' so the scanf is ok. (other than needed to check the returned value to assure the input/conversion was successful

Comment: @user3629249 Why do I see `char* input;` in `main()`?